# Why do mathematicians say "map" and "mapping" when talking about functions?

Tags: functions, terminology, math-history

I don't know if this is the right place to ask this, but I realized I've been using the word "map" to mean "function" for some time now and I have no idea why.

When did people start using "map" this way, and how is it connected to the usual meaning of "map" (a visual representation of an area)?

The only thing I can think is that charts on a manifold are very much like maps in the traditional sense, but most functions aren't manifold charts.

Comment: According to http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html it is a translation of the German *Abbildung*, which was originally used in a geometric sense then then more abstractly

Comment: Looks believable. I'll accept it if you post it as an answer.

Comment: For instance, the function from the set of points on the surface of the Earth to the set of points on the surface of your map might be an example of one of the early inspirations, although I’m not sure. In any case one imagines that the image of a function gives (it’s called an image, after all!) a kind of “picture” of the domain inside the codomain. If the codomain is, say, a plane, then such an image is an abstraction of a literal map of the domain.

Comment: in what context are you seeing it? In some courses I've had we used "map" as a concise way to say "continuous function" so we wouldn't have to keep repeating the word "continuous", and then we could reserve the word "function" for the (rare) occasion when something wasn't necessarily continuous

Comment: "Function" is a bit of a stupid name for what a function is.  Map more accurately describes the relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

According to http://jeff560.tripod.com/m.html it is a translation of the German *[Abbildung](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Abbildung)*, which was originally used in a geometric sense and then more abstractly